# Case with IN clause

Tags: mysql

My Query Looks Like,

```
SELECT `OFFER_ASSIGNED_TO`,
(CASE WHEN `OFFER_ASSIGNED_TO` IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`EMP_ID` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `f_employee_master` WHERE (`HEAD_OF_EMP`=13 OR `SUPERVISER_ADMIN`=13) AND is_active='Y') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) HI
FROM f_offer_master

WHERE fy_id=6
```

With Result Like this

```
OFFER_ASSIGNED_TO   HI
              13    N
              42    N
              13    N
              25    N
              45    N
              25    N
```

Result Of the Following  Query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`EMP_ID` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `f_employee_master` WHERE (`HEAD_OF_EMP`=13 OR `SUPERVISER_ADMIN`=13) AND is_active='Y'

is=5,8,9,10,20,21,22,25,29,33,34,35,41
```

And When I write Query Like:

```
SELECT `OFFER_ASSIGNED_TO`,
(CASE WHEN `OFFER_ASSIGNED_TO` IN (5,8,9,10,20,21,22,25,29,33,34,35,41) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) HI
FROM f_offer_master

WHERE fy_id=6
```

I get Result:

```
OFFER_ASSIGNED_TO   HI
              13    N
              42    N
              13    N
              25    Y
              45    N
              25    Y
```

That Is actually correct result.

But why my first query not giving me correct result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`EMP_ID` SEPARATOR ',') FROM `f_employee_master` WHERE (`HEAD_OF_EMP`=13 OR `SUPERVISER_ADMIN`=13) AND is_active='Y'
```

gives one result. That result is a string, namely "5,8,9,10,20,21,22,25,29,33,34,35,41".

Using that with `IN` is equivalent to `IN ('5,8,9,10,20,21,22,25,29,33,34,35,41')`, not `IN(5,8,9,10,20,21,22,25,29,33,34,35,41)`. To get the latter, you would have to get rid of the `GROUP_CONCAT`, like so:

```
CASE WHEN `OFFER_ASSIGNED_TO` IN (SELECT `EMP_ID` FROM ...
```